# How to produce "all principals" to principal - "AWS": "*"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

When I write the following code:

```
const somePolicy: PolicyStatement = new PolicyStatement({
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      resources: ["someData/*"],
      actions: ["es:*"],
      principals: [
        new ArnPrincipal("*")
      ],
      conditions: {
        IpAddress: {
          SourceIp: ["*"]
        }
      }

    });
```

I receive following access policy in the Elastic-Domain:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "someData/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "SourceIp": "*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to get this principal:

```
"Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
 },
```

How can I receive this with cdk?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Principal": "*"` is [same](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-anonymous) as `"Principal": {"AWS": "*"}`. So  it does not matter how you write it. CDK uses the first option, because there is no reason to make it longer than it needs to be.

Comment: The issue is, if I make manually a connection to Elasticsearch via the AWS management console, it works. 

If I do it in cdk, it does not work. 

If I check the difference in the access policy, the only difference is the Principal, which I described above. 

Similar issue with: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10403

Comment: I think that `"Principal": {"AWS": "*"}` only permits access from authenticated AWS entities (eg IAM User), whereas `"Principal": "*"` would include public anonymous access. However, I can't comment about how to get the CDK to select it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein both are for anonymous access without aws account.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-anonymous

For anonymous users, the following elements are equivalent: "Principal": "*"
and "Principal" : { "AWS" : "*" }